# Xpath removing spaces in between text

Tags: php, html, parsing, xpath, html-parsing

I am using following XPath to pick some data from an html page. The value I am trying to pick has some spaces in between:

```
example=value1    value2       value3
```

My XPath expression is picking the value but removes extra spaces between text like this:

```
value1 value2 value3
```

How do I make sure that extra spaces are not removed?

My xpath:

```
//*something/div/input[1]/@value
```

Sample HTML from where I am picking value:

```
<input type="radio" name='radio1' value="R92392   12132                           sdlasldkaskl                  " id='some' >
```

Note that I am getting the value as `R92392 12132 sdlasldkaskl`. But I want the spaces between text to be preserved.

Comment: Can you provide some sample XML input?

Comment: It's not the problem with the xpath. Xpath is correct and i am getting the text in value but it's stripping the spaces in between the text.

Comment: user743914, Please, edit the question and specify what exactly you want to get -- people don't have interest in trying to guess.

Comment: Silly question, but are you viewing the text as HTML in the browser? This can present the "unpreserved spaces" issue that you're seeing. Try "view source" of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My XPath engine doesn't remove the whitespaces so it must be due to a PHP setting. I'm not exactly sure about your situation as you didn't provide much code but the following might work you:

```
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true; // This setting should fix it
$doc->Load('document.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//div/input[1]/@value';
```

Comment: No, it's the space in between the text .. value is like: text1    text2         text3. Xpath is returning text1 text2 text3. I want the spaces in between preserved.

Comment: Which Sicco clearly states is not happening (as a result of the XPath expression, and is seconded by Dimitre); therefore the problem is elsewhere. Are you sure that the white-space is preserved in the attributes in the rendered HTML?

Comment: @user743914, Xpath is not "returning `text1 text2 text3`". As shown in my answer, The evaluation of the XPath expression produces the unchanged string-value of the `value` attribute. You have shown us a syntactically illegal XPath expression and you haven't shown to us the result that you want to get -- really, not helpful.

Comment: Sicco, `//*something/div/input[1]/@value` isn't a syntactically-legal XPath expression and if you try to evaluate this as XPath expression, you get an error like the one I get with Saxon: "Error in expression //*something/div/input[1]/@value: Unexpected token <name> beyond end of expression"

Comment: The problem was with the php config identified by Sicco. The class that was creating the domDocument, was using this option $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

Comment: Really? That's surprising, not preserving white space usually only removes whitespace nodes (e.g. indenting of XML source), it doesn't normally affect multiple spaces within attribute values.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, even when manually setting `preserveWhiteSpace` to `false`. The spaces are always retained.